# How to convert YUV frames to a video?

Tags: c++, image-processing, video-processing, video-encoding, yuv

How to convert set of YUV frames to a Video and later convert the video to YUV frames without any loss using C  ?(I dont want to convert it to RGB in between)

Comment: I don't understand. Aren't you just YUV throughout the whole pipeline? What are you encoding and how?!

Comment: have a look at ffmpeg library and use libavcodec and format to store YUV frame as AVI uyvy, uyvy or yuv420p, ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have a raw YUV file, you need to tell ffmpeg which pixel format/subsampling that is used. YUV have no header, so you also need to specify the width and height of the data.

The following ffmpeg commands encodes a 1080p YUV 4:2:0 to H.264 using the x264 encoder and place the result in a mp4-container. This operation is however not losless.

```
ffmpeg -f rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p -s:v 1920x1080 -r 25 -i input.yuv \
-c:v libx264 output.mp4
```

To get the YUV-frames back again, do

```
ffmpeg -i output.mp4 frames.yuv
```

If you are looking for a lossless encoder, try [HuffYUV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffyuv) or [FFV1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FFV1)